# Can run LTDC by circular buffer for easy graph drawing on STM32F7?

Tags: stm32, dma, graphics, ltdc

In stm32f746G-Discovery, I want to draw moving graph like drawing ADC output on real time.

Is it possible to make start address of LTDC buffer shifting in every single new ADC data to having graph drawing with minimum CPU intervention and memory transaction? Like by using DSP circular buffer.

One solution maybe is to copy `LTDCbuffer` by DMA from one `&LTDCbuffer+1` to `&LTDCbuffer` itself. And correcting the last vertical line of LCD. But maybe DMA use memory bandwidth.

### Update

New solution I think it's better to duplicate the buffer and shifting adress of buffer (window) in every data update. this shifting procedure involve 2x buffer size(because I set shifting periode equal to one window or buffer size). in every update, just adjusting one new column (current data to current window) and construct one new column (by dma2d, in worst case) in first buffer. After completing each window shifting equal to it's length first buffer is ready to jumping to it and progress the graph. Though I want to save matrix of data equal to LCD horizon width 480 and I opted instead of shifting them by DMA, to circulate and update it by it's pointer (I've heard of circular pointer or buffer in F7 but what is the starting point?). I think it's the fastest possible, doesn't it?

Algorithm depicted symbolically in picture:
[image: Mentioned algorithm]
Red line is moving window of LTDC and we have two buffer of 8 bit showing current state and in left side we have input which has been arrived, update of buffers occure in the next line. Red symbols are preparing write action for buffer 1 to jump in after one period of slide.Note I've ffound this have sever problem I still working on it.

And sorry because of arabic number which may cause confusion.

Comment: Yes you can use DMA to do that, and yes DMA does use memory bandwidth. But using DMA to copy a large block of the display buffer is going to be more efficient than using the M7 core to do the same job - and certainly much more efficient than regenerating the entire display from scratch for every frame. It's entirely possible for the core to carry on with other work while the DMA runs - not only would they 'share' memory bandwidth, the core also has its dedicated I-cache & D-cache as well as its pair of 'Tightly-Coupled' memory blocks which are unaffected by concurrent DMA operations.

Comment: @brhans Thanks for good DMA advise, I will update my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've developed an algorithm based on my schematic:
[image: schmatic of algorith]
I'm not sure if it's the best and it's not also the best but it works nicely in action. Schmatic is for one line LCD thus buffer pad is equal to buffer size.

source code:

```
static void graph(uint16_t val, uint32_t b1sAddr,uint32_t b2sAddr,uint32_t max_val)
{

uint32_t window_addr=LTDC_Layer1->CFBAR;

b2sAddr=b2sAddr+LCD_width;//padding buffer1 to remove buf1 and buf2 overlap
uint32_t jumpbuf;
uint32_t currbuf;
uint32_t slid_num;
static uint8_t jump=0;
static const uint32_t buf1thr=480+0xC0000000;//LCD_width+b1sAddr
static const uint32_t buf2thr=480+0xC001FFe0;//LCD_width+b2sAddr

static uint16_t tdl[LCD_width-1]={0};

if(window_addr<b2sAddr)
{
    jumpbuf=b2sAddr;
    currbuf=b1sAddr;
    if(window_addr==buf1thr)
    {
        jump=1;
    }
}
else
{
    jumpbuf=b1sAddr;
    currbuf=b2sAddr;
    if(window_addr==buf2thr)
    {
        jump=1;
    }
}
slid_num=window_addr-currbuf;

static uint16_t tdl_ind=0;


/*************Value normalization***********/
val=LCD_height*val/(max_val);
/*******************************************/

/****Artifact canceller caused by sliding****/

/*********************************************/

/******Jumping and adding new data********/
if(jump==1)
{// Jump
    LTDC_Layer1->CFBAR=jumpbuf;//jump on other LCD buffer address
    hltdc.Instance->SRCR = LTDC_SRCR_IMR;//Set the Immediate Reload type for LCD buffer


    //Adding data
    PixelFill(jumpbuf,LCD_width,val,0xff);/*addinf data*/

    window_addr=jumpbuf;
    jumpbuf=currbuf;//set jump buffer after jump
    currbuf=window_addr;//set current buffer start addr after jump


    jump=0;


}
else
{
    // Sliding ARTIFACT canceller
    PixelFill(window_addr,1,tdl[tdl_ind],0x00);
    //Slide
    LTDC_Layer1->CFBAR=window_addr+1;//increment LCD buffer address
    hltdc.Instance->SRCR = LTDC_SRCR_IMR;//Set the Immediate Reload type for LCD buffer

    // Pre-load
//  if(slid_num==0)//this condition prevent pre-loading
        PixelFill(jumpbuf,slid_num,val,0xff);


        //Adding data
        PixelFill(window_addr+1,LCD_width,val,0xff);/*addinf data*/

}
static void PixelFill(uint32_t buf,uint16_t x,uint16_t y,uint8_t val)
{
    if((y!=0)&(x!=0))
    {
        uint32_t temp;
        temp=(y-1)*LCD_width;
        *( uint8_t*)(buf+temp+x-1)=(uint8_t)val;
    }

}
static void Clear(uint32_t buf,uint8_t how)
{
uint32_t endBuf;
endBuf=how*LCD_width*LCD_height;

    uint32_t lcd_start_slide=LCD_width*100;
uint32_t lcd_position=0;
uint16_t lcdIncrement=1;

    for(uint32_t i=0;i!=endBuf;i++)
    {
        *(uint8_t*)(buf+i)=0x00;

//      for(uint32_t ii=0; ii!=50;ii++);
        if(i>lcd_start_slide)
        {
            lcdIncrement++;
            if(lcdIncrement==LCD_width)
            {

            LTDC_Layer1->CFBAR=buf+lcd_position*LCD_width;//increment LCD buffer address
            hltdc.Instance->SRCR = LTDC_SRCR_IMR;//Set the Immediate Reload type
            lcd_position++;
            lcdIncrement=0;
            }
        }

    }
    LTDC_Layer1->CFBAR=buf;//set LCD buffer address
    hltdc.Instance->SRCR = LTDC_SRCR_IMR;//Set the Immediate Reload type
}
```

And an example for how to use it on main:

```
#define window1     (uint8_t*)0xC0000000
#define window2     (uint8_t*)0xC001FE00//window1+el
      for(uint16_t i=1;i!=273;i++)
      {

          graph(i,window1,window2,272);
          for(uint32_t ii=0; ii!=8000;ii++);
//        HAL_Delay(1);
      }
```

I've tested it in STM32F746G-Discovery
Note that External SDRAM has been used for LTDC peripheral.